# How to query CouchDB all docs in database containing matched value?

Tags: couchdb

I'm fairly new to the world of CouchDB and just learned about the neat world of views. I did a bit of reading, but I'm not certain on how it works yet. My question is how could I query all the documents in a database for a matched value? I want to search a bunch of documents containing an object called `username` and only return the IDs of the documents that contain that...

How could I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Should be a straight-forward map function, unless I'm misunderstanding or missing something.

```
function (doc) {
    if (doc.username) {
        emit(doc.username);
    }
}
```

The document `_id` will be a part of your view results already, so you can just emit the username by itself. If you add `include_docs=true` to your querystring, you can get the entire document as well.

Comment: That's it? Wow, couchDB impresses like always!